# Avoiding messy flow control on boolean property lists in C#

Tags: c#, linq

We have an object of type MyObject which has several possible boolean values which we'll call Foo, Bar and Meh.

I have a list of other objects of the same type, and I only wish to select those which have a matching Foo/Bar/Meh value to the original. One way of doing so would be something like this:

```
List<MyObject> myObjects;

if(MyObject.Foo == true) {
    myObjects = existingMyObjects.Where(o => o.Foo == true).ToList();
}
else if(MyObject.Bar == true) {
    myObjects = existingMyObjects.Where(o => o.Bar == true).ToList();
}
else if(MyObject.Meh == true) {
    myObjects = existingMyObjects.Where(o => o.Meh == true).ToList();
}
```

Which is fine, but looks a bit of a mess.

In the real world, I have a similar situation except I'm dealing with nine of these boolean properties and have several instances where logic similar to above needs to live inside outer if/else statements.

That's going to be nigh-on unreadable. Is there a neater/simpler way of dealing with structures like this?

Comment: if you are comparing objects I think it's best to use the `Object.Equals` comparison vs the `==` also you could create a Generic Class where you just pass in the Objects and no matter what the name of the Class is.

Comment: @MethodMan Thanks for the suggestion. In this case, they're different objects. I need to find the ones which have matching boolean values of the same type.

Comment: If you have any scope to use a Flags enum instead of a series of booleans, then you could filter using a single statement.
myObjects = existingMyObjects.Where(x => x.Flags == MyObject.GlobalFlags).ToList();

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can combine them in the `Where()`:

```
myObjects = existingMyObjects.Where(o => o.Foo == MyObject.Foo
                                      && o.Bar == MyObject.Bar
                                      && o.Meh == MyObject.Meh).ToList();
```

You could also override `Equals()` on your `MyObject` type:

```
public class MyObject
{
    public bool Foo { get; set; }
    public bool Bar { get; set; }
    public bool Meh { get; set; }

    public MyObject()
    {
    }

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        var item = obj as MyObject;

        if (item == null)
        {
            return false;
        }

        return (item.Foo == this.Foo && item.Bar == this.Bar && item.Meh == this.Meh);
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return new { Foo, Bar, Meh }.GetHashCode();
    }
}
```

You could then do:

```
var filtered = myObjects.Where(o => obj.Equals(o)).ToList();
```

Though your question lacks clarity. Do you want all objects that equal the original as you state or do you want all object where `Foo/Bar/Meh` are `true` as your code illustrates?

Comment: This won't produce the same result as the code above if MyObject.Foo is true. However, I'm not sure if the code above is correct after reading the text...

Comment: @TomOrton IMO, his code is incorrect and doesn't match the text: `"I have a list of other objects of the same type, and I only wish to select those which have a matching Foo/Bar/Meh value to the original"`. He doesn't say that `Foo/Bar/Meh` should all be true as his code asserts, only that they should match the original value which is what this code does.

Comment: @TomOrton No, I'm aware the problem statement isn't perfect. But it isn't really the thrust of the question in this instance.

Answer (score 0):

You could combine them all into one linq statement but whilst it is certainly fewer lines of code, I'm not sure it is any less of a mess!

```
List<MyObject> myObjects = existingMyObjects.Where(o => 
    (MyObject.Foo && o.Foo == true) ||
    (MyObject.Bar && o.Bar ) ||
    (MyObject.Meh && o.Meh == true)).ToList();
```

Comment: Quite. I  was aware you could combine statements like this, but it isn't really much neater. Especially if the properties you're using are a couple of jumps down the object tree (i.e. MyObject.RelatedObject.SubObject.Bar).